# Как использовать методы из разных классов не связаных между собой в третьем

Tags: php, ооп

У меня есть класс подключения к базе `sqlClass` и в нем я прописал метод `query_exec` который исполняет SQL запросы.

Так же у меня есть еще один класс `pageNavClass` и в нем есть SQL параметр на подсчет количества ячеек определенной таблицы. (в общем планируется использовать любую таблицу), а также есть класс пользователей `usersClass` наследуемый от `sqlClass`, в классе пользователей `usersClass` есть метод `listAllUsers` который должен возвращать результат всех подсчитанных ячеек  в опред. диапазоне. через объявленный `pageNavClass` в нем.

Вопрос как связать два класса `usersClass` и `pageNavClass`, не используя наследование. Мне нужно получить метод `query_exec` из `sqlClass` чтобы можно было использовать SQL запросы в `naveNavClass` объявленный например в `usersClass`?

UPD!

```
// MySQL Connection connection.php

class Connection
{

    private $connect_result;

    function Connection(){  

        require_once ('includes/config.inc.php');

        $dsn = "mysql:host=".DBHOST.";dbname=".DBNAME.";charset=".CHARSET;
        $opt = array(
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
            PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
        );

        try {
            $this->connect_result = new PDO($dsn, DBUSER, DBPASS, $opt);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            die("Error! " . $e);
        }
        /* Исполняем все необходимое, что нужно обсолютно везде */

        $this->loadLanguage();
        $this->users_online();
        $this->AuthStatus();

        //var_dump(AUTH_STATUS);
    }

    public function getCon() {

        return $this->connect_result;
    }

    // метод выполнения запроса SQL !!!

    public function queryExec($sql, $data=false){

        $stmt = $this->getCon()->prepare($sql);

        if (!$data)
            $stmt->execute();
        else
            $stmt->execute($data);
        return $stmt;
    }
}
```

```
class PageNav {

    function navigation ($sql) {

        // Переменная хранит число сообщений выводимых на станице 
        $num = 25; 
        // Извлекаем из URL текущую страницу 
        $page = 1;

        if (!empty($_GET['page'])) {
            $page = intval($_GET['page']); 
            if ($page < 1) {
                $page = 1;
            }
        }


        // Определяем общее число сообщений в базе данных 

        $result->queryExec("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM post")->fetch();

        // Находим общее число страниц 
        $total = intval(($posts - 1) / $num) + 1; 

        // Определяем начало сообщений для текущей страницы 
        $page = intval($page); 

        // Если значение $page меньше единицы или отрицательно переходим на первую страницу 
        // А если слишком большое, то переходим на последнюю 
        if(empty($page) or $page < 0) $page = 1; 

        if($page > $total) $page = $total; 

        // Вычисляем начиная к какого номера следует выводить сообщения 
        $start = $page * $num - $num; 

        // Выбираем $num сообщений начиная с номера $start 
        $result->queryExec("SELECT * FROM post LIMIT $start, $num"); 

        // В цикле переносим результаты запроса в массив $postrow 
        while ( $postrow[] = mysql_fetch_array($result))  

        echo "<table>"; 
        for($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++) {

            echo "<tr>
                    <td>".$postrow[$i]['name']."</td>
                    <td>".$postrow[$i]['time']."</td></tr>
            <tr><td colspan=\"2\">".$postrow[$i]['text']."</td></tr>"; 
        } 
        echo "</table>"; 
    }
}
```

```
// users.class.php

class Users extends Connection{

    public function listAllEventUsers() {

        $this->navPage = new PageNav();

        $sql['count'] = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users_for_events"; 

        // $start, $num

        $sql['fetch'] = "SELECT * FROM users_for_events LIMIT ?, ?";

        $this->navPage->navigation($sql);

        return ; // array with all users 
    }
}
```

Comment: Минимально я предлагаю вам выложить ваши классы, чтобы визуально было понятно, что вы там творите.... Во-вторых: у вас не должно быть никаких наследников класса `sqlClass`, который работает с БД и соединениями к ней.... Это изуверство и изврат. Особенно не связанный с ним никак класс юзеров.... `sqlClass` у вас должен быть финальным..

Comment: обновил выше...

Comment: @jcmax, вы бы лучше UML диаграмму классов привели(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы с самого начала неверно спроектировали вашу систему. Проблема в том, что разбивая функциональность по классам так, как это сделали вы ничего кроме головной боли в среднесрочной и долгосрочной перспективе вы не получите.

Как бы я подошел к реализации вашей задачи:

1. Нужно разбить всю систему на несколько слоев. Обычно выделяют слой доступа к данным, слой бизнес логики и слой представления. Каждый из слоев отвечает за одну из общих задач, поставленных перед системой.
2. В слое бизнес логики создается *Модель Предметной Области* ([Domain Model](http://design-pattern.ru/patterns/domain-model.html)). В вашем случае это объект пользователя `User`.
3. В слое доступа к данным принимается решение о том, как именно отображать классы предметной области на БД. В самом простом случае я бы рекомендовал использовать реализацию шаблона *Активная Запись* ([Active Record](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActiveRecord)). Это немного стирает границы между слоями приложения (заодно нарушая [SRP](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF_%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8)), зато позволяет сделать код максимально простым.

   Вся логика выполнения SQL запросов переносится в класс `QueryRunner` (ваш `sqlClass`) который, по-сути является оберткой для PDO.

   Здесь к объекту пользователя добавляются функции `save` и `delete`.
4. Я бы вынес логику выборки пользователей в отдельную иерархию классов `UserFinder`. Это позволит с одной стороны вынести часть логики из класса `User`, а с другой избавится от магии статических методов поиска (вместе с реализацией [Singleton](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0_%28%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%29) в `sqlClass`).
5. Все, что связано с отображением объектов, должно быть вынесено в отдельный слой представления. Тут может быть довольно много вариантов, в детали вдаваться не буду.

Итак, вы должны получить следующую структуру классов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пример кода, связывающего все части системы вместе:

```
<?php
$sql_runner = new SqlRunner(new \PDO());
$user_finder = new UserFinder($sql_runner);
$users = $user_finder->findAllPaginated(3, 10);

// В реальном приложении, генерация HTML кода должна происходить в
// слое представления. Здесь же, для простоты, я просто использую часть
// PHP-файла как шаблон. (Никогда не делайте так!)
?>

<ul>
    <?php foreach($users as $user): ?>
        <li><?php echo $user->getLogin(); ?></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Как можно видеть, здесь вообще нет наследования, а есть только *композиция*. Вообще, наследование имеет смысл использовать только тогда, когда между сущностями есть прямое отношение родства. Во всех прочих случаях правильнее использовать композицию.

Композиция позволяет с одной стороны держать несвязанный функционал в абсолютно разных иерархиях классов, а с другой объединять взаимодействующие части системы на уровне *объектов* там, где это необходимо.

**Замечание:**

Упомянутые выше *Модель Предметной Области* и *Активная Запись* являются далеко не единственными подходами к решению вашей задачи. Есть множество других *шаблонов проектирования* которые могут оказаться полезны. Среди них стоит отметить:

- Шлюз таблицы данных ([Table Data Gateway](http://design-pattern.ru/patterns/table-data-gateway.html))
- Шлюз записи данных ([Row Data Gateway](http://design-pattern.ru/patterns/row-data-gateway.html))
- Преобразователь данных ([Data Mapper](http://design-pattern.ru/patterns/data-mapper.html))
- Сценарий Транзакции ([Transaction Script](http://design-pattern.ru/patterns/transaction-script.html))

Comment: Почти понял, но все равно спасибо в процессе пойму я думаю!

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно использовать [трейты](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.traits.php). Введены с PHP 5.4

```
trait someName {
    function query_exec() { }
}

class pageNavClass {
    use someName;
    /* ... */
}

class usersClass {
    use someName;
    /* ... */
}
```

Говоря по простому, они внедряют методы в классы, чем-то напоминает множественное наследование. Т.е. описываете метод в трейте, и можете использовать его в каком угодно классе.

Comment: мне кажеться этот механизм больше всего подходит, а так там конструкторы есть ?

Comment: @jcmax, попробуйте как тут описано: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12478124/how-to-overload-class-constructor-within-traits-in-php-5-4

Answer (score 1):

Используя телепатию:

1. Попробовать сделать методы статическими и тогда их можно будет вызывать отовсюду.
2. Наследование
3. Реализуйте функции как трейт и подключайте к любому классу через `use`
4. Что мешает создать объект двух классов в третьем и вызвать нужные функции?

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно просто использовать объект класса `sqlClass` в классах `usersClass` и `pageNavClass`.

Для начала можно пойти проторенным путем и использовать класс `sqlClass` как "одиночку" (Singleton).

А можно сразу написать через DI (Dependency Injection). Создать доп. класс с патерном "реестр" (Registry) и через него где угодно получать нужный объект для работы с БД.

Comment: При грамотной реализации DI, ни один из объектов системы не должен зависеть от контейнера объектов. По-крайней мере в такой простой схеме классов.